# Adobe XD Remove off-standing part

Tags: adobe-xd

I am creating a prototype with Adobe XD. I want to remove off-standing parts from two boxes.

Here are two pictures:

[image: Here is a corner from the white box and the orange off-standing part should be removed.]

Here is a corner from the white box and the orange off-standing part should be removed.

[image: Here is the corner from the white box.]

Here is the corner from the white box.

Comment: Seems like you should use a mask: https://www.xdguru.com/adobe-xd-guide/masking/